# TFS with Pycharm Professional on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tfs, pycharm

Is there a way to use TFS on pycharm on Ubuntu? TFS is working on windows and I'm connecting with a virtual machine normally. 
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how this is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and configure the [Azure DevOps extension for Jetbrains](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops) and have a working version of the [Team Explorer Everywhere Command Line Client (TEE-CLC)](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases/) installed.

[Steps to configure can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/intellij-faq?view=azure-devops#does-the-intellij-plug-in-support-tfvc).

> ### TFVC setup requirements
>
> You must have the TF command line tool installed to be able to use TFVC features. The minimum version supported by the plugin is 14.0.3. To install the tool, download the latest "TEE-CLC-14.*.*.zip" file and extract it to a known location. After extracting the files, you must accept the license agreement. To do so, open a Command Prompt/Terminal window, navigate to the extracted directory, and run `tf eula`. After reading the EULA, enter y to accept it. NOTE: If you forget to do this, the plugin may fail to load with a RuntimeException.
>
> For the tool to be detected by the plugin, you must set the location of the executable in the Settings/Preferences menu by following these instructions:
>
> - Go to File then Settings in the toolbar for Windows and Linux. For Mac, go to Android Studio then Preferences.
> - Choose Version Control from the left menu then TFVC.
> - In the Path to tf executable text field, navigate to the location of the tf executable.
> - Click Test to test that the executable has been found and is working as expected.
> - Click Apply then OK to save and exit.
> - If you intend to use the tf tools from the command line, you may want to add this folder to your PATH environment variable as well.
>
> If you do not want to get prompted to enter your credentials for each tf command that you run, set the `TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to `1`.
>
> ### Setting TFVC as the version control system
>
> If TFVC does not come up as your version control system (VCS) then it can be set manually. Go to the VCS dropdown menu in the toolbar and select Enable Version Control Integration. Select TFVC from the dropdown menu and click OK.

[Connecting everything to Azure DevOps / Team Foundation Server](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-connect-any-visual-studio-version/#jetbrains).

Comment: Really, -1 with no comment?!